Div textcontent inconsistently returning string
I am simply querying a web page for specific text to save to local storage and use within Chrome extension pop-up.
contentscript.js – Code I inject to webpage
function findworkspaceName() {
  let target = '#name > .company';

  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
    if (document.querySelector(target)) {
      let name = getDetails();
      chrome.storage.local.set({ name });
      observer.disconnect();
    }
  });

  observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });

  function getDetails() {
    let workspaceName = document.querySelector(target);

    console.log(workspaceName);
    console.log(workspaceName.textContent);
    return workspaceName.textContent;
  }

  // Initial check in case the element is already present
  if (document.querySelector(target)) {
    getWorkspaceDetails();
    observer.disconnect();
  }
}

findworkspaceName();

Now just focusing on getDetails function. Console logging workspaceName seems to  return the div in the console consistently. However, console logging workspaceName.textContent does not always return the textcontent from the div. Sometimes it's empty and sometimes it correctly shows the text:
function getDetails() {
 let workspaceName = document.querySelector(target);
 console.log(workspaceName); // works 100%
 console.log(workspaceName.textContent); // Is inconsistent
 return workspaceName.textContent;
}

Why could this be occuring?

It means that the element is updated after it was created in a separate mutation. You can add a second MutationObserver if textContent is empty and observe this element directly (probably with characterData:true).
